# Is there still a need for a module loader with applications that use JavaScript ES6 modules and classes?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, loader, es6-module-loader

If you code an application using ES6 modules and classes, is there any need to use a module loader framework, or is the best practice to just use a build tool to concatenate all the code into a file (or files) and include those using a normal script tag?

Comment: Some module loaders add extra functionality, for example Dojo's module loader allows you to customize the way a module is loaded.

Comment: Handling other assets such as images or fonts, can become easier with a module loader. Sometimes, multiple files needs a particular module. In that case, loaders can help to arrange the code without having to think twice about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Somebody, somewhere along the line has to load the module.

I think you're conflating compiling modules ahead of time vs loading them individually. Webpack is a module loader that outputs a single file for the browsers to use later, while the `System` API and requirejs et al load a number of individual files.

There are performance factors on both sides, particularly longer build time (when precompiling) vs longer load time (with multiple files).

Webpack, Browserify, and most other module loaders (with the notable exception of the `System` API) allow you to define some loaders for certain file types and automagically compile your (S)CSS or templates on the way through, as well as running other tools to uglify or obfuscate your code. The ES6 `System` API does not provide these features, but is a more robust runtime loader than most.

This boils down to two trade-offs:

1. support for non-JS modules (styles, templates) vs build time
2. single request and longer build vs many requests and short/no build

Evaluate them for your users (high-bandwidth vs mobile), environment (if you have two dozen CI agents, who cares if the build takes an extra 3s?), and stack (if you have a lot of template files, compiling them AOT could be important).